# Return error of model validation in result

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I create a validation for type file in ASP.NET Core 3.

This is my model validation :

```
public class MustbeImageFile : ValidationAttribute
{
    public string[] Extentions { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var file = value as IFormFile;
        var extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);

        if (file != null)
        {
            if (Extentions.Equals(extension))
            {
                return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
            }
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

and I use it on a property :

```
[MustbeImageFile(ErrorMessage = "Must be Send Image File", Extentions = new string[] { "png", "jpeg", "jpg" })]
public IFormFile Photo { get; set; }
```

This is my controller :

```
public async Task<ApiReturn> RegisterUser([FromForm]RegisterDto register)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var result = await dispatchers.SendAsync(new CreateUserCommand()
                {
                    Email = register.Email,
                    UserName = register.UserName,
                    FirstName = register.FirstName,
                    LastName = register.LastName,
                    PhoneNumber = register.PhoneNumber
                });

        if (result.Success)
        {
            return Ok();
        }

        return BadRequest(result.ErrorMessage);
    }

    return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```

I send a pdf file and I expect to get this error:

> Must be image file

but I get this error instead:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ValidationProblemDetails

What's the problem? How can I show my error details instead of just `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ValidationProblemDetails` ?

Comment: `ErrorMessage` inherits from ValidationAttribute. So just delete `public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }` from MustbeImageFile class.

Answer (score 0):

In the `MustbeImageFile` method, you wrote `the opposite logic` to determine if the current extension is included in Extentions.

Change MustbeImageFile method like this :

```
//...       
if (!Extentions.Equals(extension))
{
    return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
}
//...
```

Comment: How do you want to present error messages? Does it appear behind the file upload control like the error message of form validation? If so, you can display the error message by adding a validation control. If not, it is recommended that you elaborate and provide your front-end code to us for reference .

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to define how the execution pipeline should treat `BadRequest` errors. For instance, you can write your own `InvalidModelStateResponseFactory` to specify the format of the error message. In your case, you can read the error message from your custom validation attribute.

Have a look at my answer [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59210281/why-do-we-no-longer-need-to-manually-validate-models-in-higher-versions-of-asp-n/59211386#59211386)